# how make inline textedit and imageview

Tags: android, xml, android-relativelayout

I want to set image and textedit in 1 line but don't can :(

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.octoplus.google.camera.settings.VideoSettingsActivity">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="200px"
        android:layout_height="200px"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/image_view"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

for example have vine app.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7gu5bbuZn2IZkNRbHp2WEFNNnc/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try placing your ImageView and EditText inside a LinearLayout with `android:orientation="horizontal"`. Now you can place your two elements next to each other.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.octoplus.google.camera.settings.VideoSettingsActivity">

 <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="200px"
    android:layout_height="200px"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<EditText android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/image_view"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```